# clarity on clear property CSS[style="clear:both;" ]

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="position:sticky">
tto
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>
```

With the above code sticky position is not working. I have tried keeping all this inside the container which somehow made the "position: sticky" to work.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sticky">
tto
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>
</div>

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Later on to my surprise I saw someone fixing everything with this code.

```
<div style="position:sticky;top:0">
tto
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> //extra div needed
```

Can someone please explain how the "clear: both" attribute in a different container make it work and what is going on here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried giving the `top: 0` without the last div element `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`. In this case also it was not working.

Comment: It's not the `clear`. If you try your second block of code -which works, it's because `position: sticky` requires the `top` property - which has been added. `position: sticky` is essentially, `position: relative` until it's scrolled to, then it mimics `position: fixed`. You need the `top` property so it knows how to anchor once it becomes "fixed"

Comment: If it's not working without the container, set your body element to have `position: relative`. Sticky elements also need a parent to reference its position against.